How does NVM change my PATH?
I use fish as my default shell, but installed nvm (Node Version Manager) in a bash terminal, since the installer is not compatible with fish. However, after running nvm use in bash, the path variable from my fish shell is changed as well. It's persistent across reboots, even when I don't touch bash at all. I can't find out where nvm writes the entry to make it available to fish. Any ideas?

Can you show us some specific output? What was added to your $PATH? How exactly did you install nvm? Why would you install it in a bash session? If all you need is to run the installer with bash, you can run bash /path/to/install.script from within your fish (for next time). Also, how do you launch fish? Do you open a bash shell and then run fish?

Apparently, fish inherits PATH and some other such variables from its parent process (emphasis mine):

$PATH
$PATH is an environment variable containing the directories that
fish searches for commands. Unlike other shells, $PATH is a list, not
a colon-delimited string.
Fish takes care to set $PATH to a default, but typically it is just
inherited from fish’s parent process and is set to a value that makes
sense for the system - see Exports.

To illustrate:
## This is a bash shell
terdon@oregano ~ $ PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/some/random/dir"
## Here, I move to fish
terdon@oregano ~ $ fish
## Fish has inherited the new path
terdon@oregano ~> echo $PATH 
/usr/bin /bin /some/random/dir

You haven't told us how you launch fish, but presumably, you are either launching it manually from a bash session, or your nvm has made the PATH change in a file read by dash as well as bash (e.g. ~/.profile). In any case, since fish inherits the $PATH from its parent, that's where your culprit is.

Hi, thanks for the answer! I set fish via sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish for my user, so I don't think it's launched via bash, but I don't know for sure. It's the default shell, with or without GUI. Yes, it's not only fish's path but some global path, but grep -R ".nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12" . did not return anything useful.

Yeah, but your login shell is dash and that's probably why the path changes @fweth. I would guess your GUI login manager reads your ~/profile file. By the way, you don't need sudo for chsh, just run it as your regular user.

Thank you so much @terdon, it was in ~/profile but didn't contain the exact string v12.22.12, instead run some nvm script. Now I removed it from .profile but keep it in .bashrc which is perfect, I just open bash when I want to use nvm and in fish everything is like before, so node refers to the system node version.
